# Можно ли создавать звуки в JS?

Tags: javascript

Дамы и Господа, возник вопрос, можно ли на  JS создавать звуки? 
Помню в детстве, я писал код на `basic-ке`, когда еще IBM 386 или IBM 486, был  мечтой мечтой моего поколения))))....  Так вот в `basic` был оператор `BEEP`.  Вопрос: есть ли некий аналог данного оператора на JS?

Comment: О 80386 и 80486, классика.

Comment: ДА-ДА_ДА....))))

Comment: Да, как время летит быстро, еще вчера 80386 был мечтой, а тут уже квантовые процессоры тестируют.

Comment: Боюсь представить, возможности))))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я вижу два варианта

1. Добавить тег [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)
2. Воспользоваться [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)

Первый вариант позволит вопроизводить заранее записанные треки. Второй также позволит генерировать звуки.

Пример из MDN:

```js
// создаем аудио контекст
var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// создаем OscillatorNode - генератор
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

oscillator.type = 'square';
// задаем частоту в герцах
oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(440, audioCtx.currentTime);
oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);

// запускаем пищалку
oscillator.start();
// говорим "горшочек не вари" через 300 мс
setTimeout(e => oscillator.stop(), 300);
```

См. также:

1. [Making Music in the Browser – Web Audio API, Part 1](https://www.keithmcmillen.com/blog/making-music-in-the-browser-web-audio-api-part-1/) (по-английски)
2. [Violent Theremin demo](http://mdn.github.io/violent-theremin/) (демо)
3. [OscillatorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode) (по-английски)

Comment: tutankhamun, искал, не нашел, будь другом или ссылку или кусок кода

Comment: не воспроизводить, а именно создавать

Comment: Тогда первый вариант не подойдет.

Comment: Подойдет, просто тогда создавать на базе существущих файлов.

Comment: tutankhamun, не беда, а что на счет 2-го варианта?

Comment: @Air дополнил примером (можно прямо тут пробовать -> "Выполнить код")

Comment: Уже))))  я говорил, что ты умница?)))))   Благодарю за пример, все супер, пойду ковыряться....)))

Answer (score 1):

Даже трудно сказать, работал ли пример, который я хочу предложить 2 года назад, когда был задан этот вопрос, в общем, простой пример аналога функции `beep() на basic` с параметрами частоты звука в герцах и длительности в секундах с применением `WebAudio Api`:

```js
function beep(f, d) { // частота в герцах, длительность в секундах
  var ctx = new AudioContext();
  var oscillator = ctx.createOscillator();
  oscillator.frequency.value = f;
  oscillator.connect(ctx.destination);
  oscillator.start();
  oscillator.stop(d);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="beep(1000, 0.5)"> старт </button>
```

Правда, если вопрос подразумевает аналог функции beep() на basic, написанный на чистом JS, то возможно лучше исключить WebAudio Api. Чуть больше кода, зато на чистом JS:

```js
function beep(f, d) {
  var volume = 10000,
    u1 = -volume,
    u2 = volume,
    u = u1,
    samples = [],
    titlestring = decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob("UklGRgAAAABXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAIARMKsAAAQwrECAAQAEABkYXRh"))),
    title = [];
  for (i = 0; i < titlestring.length; i++) title[i] = titlestring.charCodeAt(i);
  for (i = 0; i < d * 44100; i++) {
    u += f;
    if (u > u2) u = u1;
    samples[i] = u;
  }
  var outbuffer = new Int16Array(title.length / 2 + samples.length * 2);
  for (i = 0; i < title.length; i += 2) outbuffer[i / 2] = title[i] + title[i + 1] * 256;
  for (i = 0; i < samples.length * 2; i++) outbuffer[i * 2 + 44] = outbuffer[i * 2 + 45] = samples[i];
  var audio = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([outbuffer])));
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="beep(435, 0.5)"> старт </button>
```

Кто-то даже спросил, можно ли на PHP напиcать аналог `beep() на basic` :) В таком случае не полхо бы, чтобы каждый современный язык её включал. Плюс ещё бы реанимировать особенность старых текстовых редакторов, когда в тексте встречался служебный символ с кодом 7, это вызывало beep() во время отображения текста.

Comment: Пример работал и по сей день работает

Answer (score -1):

И так:

```html
<audio id="beep" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-01a.wav" 
       autostart="false" >
</audio>

<a onclick="playSound();">Click me to hear a beep</a>

<script>
    function playSound() {
          var sound = document.getElementById("beep");
          sound.play();
     }
</script>
```